# Backbone.js events on templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am trying to assign a event to a button using backbones events: .
I gave it a try how all the tuts done it but nothing has worked so far. My suspicion is that I can't add events because the content of $el hasnt been updated yet (I load in a template useing underscore). So my question would be how can I assign events to classes which arent loaded in at the start?

My code is on Github in the repo https://github.com/PITS/bluLime-CMS

The file I am working on is located under ui/scripts/views/UserPage.js.

```
var UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {},
    render: function() {

        var data = {
        };
        var compiled = _.template(UserPage, data);

        $.when($('.main').html(compiled)).then(function() {
            this.$el = $(".userEdit");
            console.log(this.$el);
        });
    },
events: {
    "click .header button": "openPreview"
},
openPreview: function() {
    alert("HI");
}
```

The Template is located in ui/scripts/views/templates/UserPage.js

```
<div class="userEdit">
 <div class="header">
    <h2>
        Edit Users
    </h2>
    <button>

    </button>
</div>
</div>
```

PS: I have already tryed to solve the problem but I failed

Comment: How are you creating the view?

Comment: The events will be bound to the elements when the template is rendered.. Where are you rendering the `UserView`  in the first place

Comment: in the jquery when then statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your events aren't being delegated to the correct element after you change `this.$el`. Instead of directly setting `this.$el`, use [`View.setElement`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement). It will deal with event re-delegation for you.

Also, you'll need to create a `view` variable to keep the reference to `this`, since the context inside the `then` callback is no longer the view.

Your render function should look like this:

```
render: function() {

    var data = {
    };
    var compiled = _.template(UserPage, data);
    var view = this;

    $.when($('.main').html(compiled)).then(function() {
        view.setElement($(".userEdit"));
        console.log(view.$el);
    });
}
```